# PHP - Ordenar y agrupar valores de un arreglo multidimencional subiendo multiples archivos

Tags: php, array

Tengo el siguiente formulario que al enviarlo con múltiples imágenes me genera un array multidimencional con todos los datos ordenados por defecto.

**Formulario HTML y PHP:**

```
<?php

if(array_key_exists('send', $_POST)) {
    echo "<pre>"; print_r($_FILES);
}

?>

<html>
    <body>
        <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="" method="POST">
            <input name="image[]" type="file" multiple />
            <input type="submit" name="send" value="Send" />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Al enviarlo me genera un array de este tipo:**

```
$file1 = array(
    'imagen' => array(
        'name'      => array(
            'Image_name',
            'Image_name'
        ),
        'type'      => array(
            'jpg',
            'jpg'
        ),
        'tmp_name'  => array(
            'jpg',
            'jpg'
        ),
        'error'     => array(
            0,
            0
        ),
        'size'      => array(
            '200',
            '200'
        )
    )
);
```

Yo necesito ordenar los datos con PHP y ciclos foreach preferiblemente, de este array de manera mas sencilla y que los valores puedan estar juntos.

**Ejemplo, algo similar a esto:**

```
$file2 = array(
    array(
        'name' => 'Image_name',
        'type' => 'jpg',
        'tmp_name' => 'jpg',
        'error' => 0,
        'size' => 200
    ),
    array(
        'name' => 'Image_name',
        'type' => 'jpg',
        'tmp_name' => 'jpg',
        'error' => 0,
        'size' => 200
    )
);
```

*Agradezco mucho su ayuda.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes utilizar array_map para eso.

Ejemplo:

```
<?php
$file1 = array(
    'imagen' => array(
        'name'      => array(
            'Image_name',
            'Image_name'
        ),
        'type'      => array(
            'jpg',
            'jpg'
        ),
        'tmp_name'  => array(
            'jpg',
            'jpg'
        ),
        'error'     => array(
            0,
            0
        ),
        'size'      => array(
            '200',
            '200'
        )
    )
);

$array = array_map(null, $file1['imagen']['name'], $file1['imagen']['type'], $file1['imagen']['tmp_name'], $file1['imagen']['error'], $file1['imagen']['size']);


print_r($array);
```

Resultado:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Image_name
            [1] => jpg
            [2] => jpg
            [3] => 0
            [4] => 200
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Image_name
            [1] => jpg
            [2] => jpg
            [3] => 0
            [4] => 200
        )

)
```

Si quieres conservar las claves del array:

```
<?php
$file1 = array(
    'imagen' => array(
        'name'      => array(
            'Image_name',
            'Image_name'
        ),
        'type'      => array(
            'jpg',
            'jpg'
        ),
        'tmp_name'  => array(
            'jpg',
            'jpg'
        ),
        'error'     => array(
            0,
            0
        ),
        'size'      => array(
            '200',
            '200'
        )
    )
);


function array_map_key($name, $type, $tmp_name, $error, $size){
        $tmp_array['name']  = $name;
        $tmp_array['type']  = $type;
        $tmp_array['tmp_name'] = $tmp_name;
        $tmp_array['error']     = $error;
        $tmp_array['size']  = $size;
        return $tmp_array;
}

$array = array_map('array_map_key', $file1['imagen']['name'], $file1['imagen']['type'], $file1['imagen']['tmp_name'], $file1['imagen']['error'], $file1['imagen']['size']);


print_r($array);
```

Resultado:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => Image_name
            [type] => jpg
            [tmp_name] => jpg
            [error] => 0
            [size] => 200
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => Image_name
            [type] => jpg
            [tmp_name] => jpg
            [error] => 0
            [size] => 200
        )

)
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, funciona perfecto.